# Cordova 3.6 File Plugin not working in android nougat

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins, worklight-studio, android-7.0-nougat

Currently i am using cordova 3.6 in my application. I have used file plugin for accessing the files. It was working fine till Marshmallow, when i installed the app in nougat it was not working. While i debugging the code, i found that **window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL** function not working properly in nougat. 
I tried search on google about this and in jira of cordova project too. Found the below links.

1. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11592
2. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11625

But the details given in above links are not much helpful to solve my problem. 
Is it possible to update the file without updating the cordova core library version.
Since am using worklight, i search on that way too. And i got below article.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/05/mobilefirst-platform-compatibility-for-android-n/

Please help me to figure it out the solution for the file plugin issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed by worklight. They have released latest patch, you can get it from the below link.

https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other+software/IBM+MobileFirst+Platform+Foundation&release=7.0.0.0&platform=Linux&function=all

Answer (score 0):

Since the Cordova issue is resolved, you should open a PMR (support ticket) for IBM in order to integrate the fixes into a new iFix release.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Will do in that way. Anyway i will try a work around by adding all the new files of cordova plugin and rename the class name and plugin name. Hope it will help me to solve the issue soon. Let me know if there is any mistake in my plan of action.